# java limit access to setters on a class

Tags: java

How do I do this? In my Java application, I am trying to define the following 2 "types" -

1. A **DataSet** type that lets you define a dataset and do things with
   it
2. A **DataElement** type that lets you define a dataelement and do things with it

There are getters and setters on **DataElement** but I want **ONLY DataSet** to be able to mutate a **DataElement**.

I don't want to make DataElement setters package private as I want to allow my DataElement implementation to be extended/overridden.

I also want DataElement type to be a class for persistence with Hibernate (Unless that is not a requirement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Facade` pattern to make instances of DataElement that DataSet returns immutable.

Answer (score 1):

ControlAltDel beat me to it; I think the Facade pattern makes sense here. Here's the approach I came up with. By using a public interface that only allows read-access, you can then do whatever you need nested within your package/`DataSet` class.

```
public interface DataElementReadable {
    public int getElementInt();
    public String getElementString();
    // etc.
}

protected class DataSet {
    private class DataElementReadableWritable implements DataElementReadable {
        int getElementInt() { return ... }
        void setElementInt(int elementInt) { ... }

        // etc.
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I want my DataElement type to be a class though, since I need to persist it with Hibernate. How would this work if DataElement was to be a top-level class?

Comment: @BiAct you should download the source code with the JDK if you don't already have it and look at how the `Facade` pattern that I mentioned is used to create an immutable List, Set, or Map in `Collections`. Essentially, it provides a facade on the List/Set/Map, but with the setters set to throw exceptions stating the instance's immutability

Comment: @controlaltdel I checked the facade pattern out and like musical_coder pointed out this seems it might require dataelement to be an inner class of dataset but I want to persist dataelement too and thought it would be easier if dataelement were a top level class

Comment: Unless you are suggesting I leave dataelement as a top level class and make it package private with the facade class implementing the right interface however I also want to allow data element to be extended

Comment: @BiAct Just like how you can use `Collections` to make an `ArrayList` immutable, your class does not have to be an inner class